# In how many ways can methods be added to a ruby object?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, dynamic-code

When it comes to run time introspection and dynamic code generation I don't think ruby has any rivals except possibly for some lisp dialects. The other day I was doing some code exercise to explore ruby's dynamic facilities and I started to wonder about ways of adding methods to existing objects. Here are 3 ways I could think of:

```
obj = Object.new

# add a method directly
def obj.new_method
  ...
end

# add a method indirectly with the singleton class
class << obj
  def new_method
    ...
  end
end

# add a method by opening up the class
obj.class.class_eval do
  def new_method
    ...
  end
end
```

This is just the tip of the iceberg because I still haven't explored various combinations of `instance_eval`, `module_eval` and `define_method`. Is there an online/offline resource where I can find out more about such dynamic tricks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ruby Metaprogramming](http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/) seems to be a good resource. (And, linked from there, [The Book of Ruby](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/The-Book-Of-Ruby).)

Answer (score 3):

If `obj` has a superclass, you can add methods to `obj` from the superclass using `define_method` [(API)](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000497) as you mentioned. If you ever look at the Rails source code, you'll notice that they do this quite a bit.

Also while this isn't exactly what you're asking for, you can easily give the impression of creating an almost infinite number of methods dynamically by using `method_missing`:

```
def method_missing(name, *args)
  string_name = name.to_s
  return super unless string_name =~ /^expected_\w+/
  # otherwise do something as if you have a method called expected_name
end
```

Adding that to your class will allow it to respond to any method call which looks like

```
@instance.expected_something
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the book [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) which is published by the publishers of the pickaxe book.